# split a div into four equal div

Tags: css, centering

What I would like to do is as follows-

```
------------------------------------
|    ------------- -------------   |
|    |     1      |     2      |   |
|    |            |            |   |
|    ------------- -------------   |
|    |     3      |     4      |   |
|    |            |            |   |
|    ---------------------------   |
------------------------------------
```

So far I tried-

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#top {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 15%;
}
#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85%;
}
.inner {
  width: 49%;
  height: 49%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
</div>
```

But all `inner` divs are left aligned. How can I align center horizontally within `bottom` div?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but for now I'm feeling some flexbox smell here ;)

Comment: can you explain what you mean by center horizontally?

Comment: Here is fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/nj6qfgxn/

Comment: I have updated the question. Look at the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` and you can use 50% because the border gets calculated in the percentage.

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#top {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 15%;
}
#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85%;
}
.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: One thing again, If I want to absolutely center the content of inner divs?

Comment: if you want to center the content of div use this------------ ---------------- .inner{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
    border:1px solid black;   
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

Answer (score 1):

The flexbox way:

https://jsfiddle.net/hfxx1awp/4/

```
#top{
  background-color:red;
  height:15%;
}

#bottom{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:85%;
  background-color:blue;
}

#bottom > *{
  flex-basis: auto;
  width:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid black;     
}
```

And here's a more advanced way, with scss and gutters. Obviously you could further refine it adding zero margin for last row and also making a mixin out of it:

https://jsfiddle.net/hfxx1awp/5/

```
#bottom > *{
  $columns: 2;
  $gutter_width: 15px;
  $gutters: $columns - 1;
  $gutter_offset: $gutter_width * $gutters / $columns;
  width: calc( 50% - #{$gutter_offset} );
  flex-basis: auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid black; 

  &:nth-child(#{$columns}n){
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  // apply margin
  @for $i from 0 through ($gutters){
    @if($i != 0){
      &:nth-child(#{$columns}n+#{$i}){
        margin-right: $gutter_width;
      }
    }
  }

  margin-bottom: $gutter_width;
}
```